# My javascript codes won't work?

Tags: javascript, html

My Html page codes :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  </head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <script>
        function LengthConverter() 
        {
        var inchRef,inchtoCmResultRef;
        var inch,centimetres;
        inchRef=document.getElementById("inchToCmValue");
        inchtoCmResultRef=document.getElementById("inchtoCmResult");
        inch=Number(inchRef.value);
        centimetres=Number(inchtoCmResultRef.value)
        centimetres=2.54*inch
        inchtoCmResultRef.innerText=centimetres;
      
        }
        function LengthConvertercmToinch()
        {
        var inch2Ref,cmtoInchResultRef;
        var inchTwo,centimetresTwo;
        inch2Ref=document.getElementById("cmToInchValue");
        cmtoInchResultRef=document.getElementById("cmToInchRe");
        inchTwo=Number(inch2Ref.value);
        centimetresTwo=Number(cmtoInchResultRef.value)
        inchTwo=centimetresTwo/2.54
        cmtoInchResultRef.innerText=inchTwo;
        }
    </script>
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js">
    
    </script>
  <body>
        <!-- Always shows a header, even in smaller screens. -->
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Length -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Length</span>
      <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
      <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Length</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="Mass.html">Mass</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Change conversion</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Length</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="Mass.html">Mass</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="page-content"><div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"><h3>Centimetres to inches</h3>
<!-- Numeric Textfield with Floating Label -->
<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" id="cmToInchValue">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="cmToInchValue">Centimetres...</label>
    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Input is not a number!</span>
  </div>
</form>
<!-- Raised button with ripple --><h4>Inches:</h4>
<span id="cmToInchRe"></span><button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect" onclick="LengthConvertercmToinch()">Convert to Inches</button>
</div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"><h3>Inches to centimetres</h3>
<!-- Numeric Textfield with Floating Label -->
<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" id="inchToCmValue">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="inchToCmValue">Inches...</label>
    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Input is not a number!</span>
  </div>
</form>

<!-- Raised button with ripple --><h4>Centimetres:</h4>
<span id="inchtoCmResult"></span> <button onclick="LengthConverter()" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect">Convert to Centimetres</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know it's a long piece of code but I can't find the mistake?

I basically copied the codes from the material design lite(mdl)website to get the interface to create a webpage to convert cm to inches and vice versa and it also links to a webpage for mass by making minor changes to the code.

I input the converting function and onclick function myself.

But only the right side of the webpage works while the left column returns null?Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code in   "LengthConvertercmToinch()" observe here just added one variable

```
  function LengthConvertercmToinch()
    {
    var inch2Ref,cmtoInchResultRef;
    var inchTwo,centimetresTwo,inchTwo1;
    inch2Ref=document.getElementById("cmToInchValue");
    cmtoInchResultRef=document.getElementById("cmToInchRe");
    inchTwo=Number(inch2Ref.value);
    centimetresTwo=Number(cmtoInchResultRef.value)
    inchTwo1=inchTwo/2.54
    cmtoInchResultRef.innerText=inchTwo1;
    }
```

I think now your problem has resolved

Let me know if your problem is solved

Comment: It works thanks!But I don't  get why I need to assign it to a new variable?It works without a third variable for the inch to cm function tho

Comment: you can minimize last three lines of that method   
        "centimetresTwo=Number(cmtoInchResultRef.value)
        inchTwo1=inchTwo/2.54
        cmtoInchResultRef.innerText=inchTwo1;"    into  "cmtoInchResultRef.innerText=inchTwo/2.54;" that statement "centimetresTwo=Number(cmtoInchResultRef.value)" doesn't mean so you can remove that statement

Comment: But I included the statement cmtoInchResultRef.innerText=inchTwo?Doesn't that mean the same thing?

Comment: I assigned a new variable for my mass html and it doesn't work?Really not getting the concept of this

Comment: Hi Lim sook yee,     
I hope here you have a clear explanation 

inch2Ref=document.getElementById("cmToInchValue"); // used to get the input value  

cmtoInchResultRef=document.getElementById("cmToInchRe");// assigning the element to variable where we want to displace the result

cmtoInchResultRef.innerText=inchTwo/2.54; // and finally this to compute and insert the value 

comment if you have any queries